# What are stepper motors commonly used in?

Tags: stepper-motor

I like finding motors and parts from recycled electronics and I want to find some stepper motors. What are these most often used in?

Comment: Printers, scanners. The best ones are in the older models. Some small motors can be found in floppy drives and CD-ROMs (tray open/close mechanism).

Comment: @EugeneSh. What about a laminator? Will that have one?

Comment: Never seen one..Basically the stepper motors are used where precise position control is needed. I am not sure if the laminator needs one.

Comment: The best source used to be 5.25 Inch floppy drives. Right now the best source is dx, ebay or aliexpress...

Comment: What kind of stepper motor are you looking for? Some might not be that high resolution (steps per rev), others wont have the torque you may need.

Answer (score -1):

Your best source would be old HDDs.

Comment: You sure about that? I think HDDs have used BLDC or induction motors for quite some time now.

Comment: VERY old low-end hard drives (late 1970s and early 1980s) used stepper motors for head positioning, but for the last 30 years, they've used voice coils for head positioning and brushless DC motors for the spindles. Floppy drives and optical drives have very tiny steppers in them for head positioning.